# How to fix Uncaught ReferenceError: input1Ref is not defined in react.js

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hooks, focus, ref

I have two different input and I want to make sure that once I entered value into the first input, it should automatically shift focus to the next input but unfortunately I am having this error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: input1Ref is not defined'.

What I have tried is shown below:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";

  const [OTPInput, setOTPInput] = useState([0, 0, 0, 0]);
  const input1Ref = useRef(null);
  const input2Ref = useRef(null);


const handleChangeInput1 = (e) => {
    setOTPInput([e.target.value, OTPInput[1]]);

    if (e.target.value != "") {
      input2Ref.current.focus();
    }
  };

 return (
    <>
           <div className="otp-verification-inputs">
              <input
                placeholder=""
                type="tel"
                maxLength="1"
                name="otpValue1"
                ref={input1Ref}
                onChange={handleChangeInput1}
              />
              <input
                placeholder=""
                type="tel"
                maxLength="1"
                name="otpValue2"
                onChange={(e) =>
                  setOTPInput([
                    OTPInput[0],
                    e.target.value
                  ])
                }
              />
        </div>
```

Comment: when exactly this happens? when you call the component or when you try to change the value of the input?

Comment: @Ahmed Sbai  Oh! I just got the problem fixed myself now. It was a misspelled of word.